# issue in retrieving value type in text box using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("input[name='room_type']").focus(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select[name='htl_name'] option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";

          });

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"",
            data:  $("form#insertform").serialize(),

            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".res").html(data);

                $('#test').html(data);


            }
            });  
            var str = $("form").serialize();
            $(".res").text(str);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Here I'm getting the value typed in the input box htl_name but the whole page reloading. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Use jsfiddle.com to upload your full page in a working environment :)

Comment: if you only wanted to get the typed value of textbox why are you doing a self post back
you need to somehow describe your intention

Comment: @Kiarash I want to list the items in the very next select box base on the value in the text box. But I'm getting the value exactly. But along with the value whole page again reloading. I'm not an expert in this still ,with out posting the value ,how can i retrieve the value

Comment: input box htl_name is wrong.Bcoz you updated as select[name='htl_name'] in jquery

Comment: @Sundar both htl_name and room_type are text boxes. changed select[name='htl_name'] into input[name='htl_name']. but still the same

Comment: try e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
      $("input[name='room_type']").focus(function (e) {
      var str = "";
      $("select[name='htl_name'] option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";

          });

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"",
            data:  $("form#insertform").serialize(),

            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".res").html(data);

                $('#test').html(data);


            }
            });  
            var str = $("form").serialize();
            $(".res").text(str);
           e.preventDefault(); //if this doesn't work, replace it with "return false"
    });
    });
```

Comment: Did you do it correctly? also, upload your code(HTML+JS), so I can have look what's wrong